# how to loadtxt using numpy if the line separator is present

Tags: python, numpy

Dear experts i have a problem, I have a file that contain both numerics,strings and separator like ..... how to import it using numpy.loadtxt.. I am getting errors like like Convert each value according to its column and store

ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 3

my code is given below

import numpy as np
np.loadtxt('file',dtype=str)

i am getting error

data file

```
10.0        c1
80.0        c2
...............
10.0        mr
2.0         no
```

hope some experts will definitely help me on resolving this issue

Comment: `loadtxt` works with an open file, or anything that feeds it lines.  So you could pass the file through a function that strips out the offending lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass characters that mark lines as comments:

```
>>> numpy.loadtxt('test.txt', comments='..', dtype=str)
array([['10.0', 'c1'],
       ['80.0', 'c2'],
       ['10.0', 'mr'],
       ['2.0', 'no']], dtype='<U4')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because [numpy.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) states: Each row in the text file must have the same number of values. Use another method or you could erase the dots from the file before you run the `loadtxt` command

Comment: Thanks every experts for your support